# How to view image on front-end stored in Lumen?

Tags: php, lumen

I want to display images saved on my Lumen framework(v7.2.2) inside storage/app/public(i am not sure if this is right place to store them) in my Angular front-end. At the moment i am putting files manually there(haven't made yet forms to upload photos and controller method in my back-end). In my database i am storing a **path** to file for example "advrt_photos/fred1256.jpg".
On my front-end when i am trying to access the file i am getting

```
"GET http://linktomyapi.test/storage/app/public/advrt_photos/fred1256.jpg 404 (Not Found)"
```

I am not sure what i should do to get access to these files because there is no php artisan storage:link command on Lumen.

Comment: `storage:link` is just a shortcut to creating a symlink. You can do `ln -s` on the server to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm!